# Rails nested Ajax forms on ajax:send only for top form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an ajax form that has a remote true link_to and a nested remote form that lead to other actions.

I need to use a listener to perform some actions on the top level form:

```
$(document).on('ajax:send', 'form[data-remote=true]', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $form = $(this);
    ...
    $form.unbind("ajax:success").on('ajax:success', function (data) {
        // do something
    }).on('ajax:complete', function () {
        // do something else
    });
});
```

Problem is that the nested link_to and nested form trigger this listener no matter what I do.

I end up deviating from the Rails standards sadly, which is not what my problem is here, just HOW do you tell the `on('ajax:send)` function to only work IF the form is the top one?
I was thinking maybe to grand the URL from the ajax:send returned data with

```
$(document).on('ajax:send', 'form[data-remote=true]', function (event) {
  [data, status, xhr] = event.detail
...
```

but this feels like a nightmare. Any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have a form inside another form?

Comment: My form iterates through objects and creates separate forms for each. The only way I can get the link and form OUTSIDE the main form is with position absolute and all kinds of crazy monkey patching.